# Combining orthophoto and DEM to export xyz-CSV

Tags: qgis, point, dem, xyz, orthophoto

I have a georeferenced orthophoto and a DEM as tiff-file. For my further workflow I want to export x,y,z (x,y from the orthophoto and z from the DEM).
I already managed to create a point layer and click a couple of points, which I want to use as control points. After clicking I exported the new layer as CSV & turned GEOMETRY on AS_XYZ.
It already works fine for X & Y, but not for the Z-Coordinate. I guess, because the height is saved as an attribute in the DEM[image: z in cm].
Does anybody have an idea how to connect x,y and z?
(the DEM and orthophoto aren't snapped).

Comment: look in the processing toolbox for the point sampling tool.

Comment: @csk Thanks for your tip! The point sampling tool solved my problem.